# Is it possible to use image background "linear-gradient(to left, green 70%,red 30%)" to react native app?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, background-image, linear-gradients, css-gradients

I able to made it by html,css,jquery

**here is my html code :**

```
  ` var total_time_in_sec = 10
    var also_have_in_sec = 9;
    setInterval(() => {
        if (also_have_in_sec > 1) {
            var green_percent = Math.round(also_have_in_sec / total_time_in_sec * 100);

            if ((100 - green_percent) <= 50) {
                var color1 = "green " + green_percent + "%";
                var color2 = "red " + (100 - green_percent) + "%";
                var str = "linear-gradient(to left," + color1 + "," + color2 + ")";
            } else {
                var color1 = "red " + (100 - green_percent) + "%";
                var color2 = "green " + green_percent + "%";
                var str = "linear-gradient(to right," + color1 + "," + color2 + ")";
            }
            $("img").css("background", str);
            also_have_in_sec = also_have_in_sec - 1;
        } else {
            clearInterval();
            $("img").css("background", "red");
        }
        console.log(green_percent);
    }, 1000);`
```

**Output is given below:**
[image]

Now I want to use an image with this kinds of background in react-native app.percentage available from backend. setTimeout and clearInterval is not mandatory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not apply linear gradient style as you described to the react native apps.

However, in order to display linear gradient in react native apps, [this library](https://github.com/react-native-linear-gradient/react-native-linear-gradient) might be useful.